# Mysql query to get lowest values from table using comparison

Tags: mysql

I have price table with three columns id,price,product_id. product_id can contain multiple prices. I have to get lowest price product_id when query perform in mysql, but I am not getting as expected.

My Mysql fiddle query link:
[mysql fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca76/3)

In this table product_id 101 has 4999 as low value but I am getting another price 5000

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: SELECT MIN(price),product_id 
FROM price pr WHERE price >= 2000 AND price <= 15000 
group by product_id order by price ASC  , if you want to get the column id, it is still doable but a bit expensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `min` function:

```
SELECT id,min(price),product_id 
FROM price pr 
WHERE price >= 2000 AND price <= 15000 group by product_id order by price ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT id,price,product_id FROM price order by price ASC limit 1
```